# Is it possible to use a GUI based text editor (e.g. Eclipse) from the terminal?

Tags: c, git, eclipse, terminal

I'd like to use terminal for all of my normal git and compiling and running processes (my school has a server that is linked to my repo on bitbucket), but I really don't like terminal-based text editing software such as Emacs and Vim. Is it possible to open and edit files from the terminal using a GUI based text editor? The reason I'm asking is because the terminal is the only way I can access the server files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The terminal can be used to launch GUI programs. Depending upon the operating system, the commands will look different. Please google around a little bit more to get a more well established Q. Thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414577/388859

Comment: Is the [_Remote System Explorer_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols#group-details) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Aw, but vim is the best! :) Well, you can use nano, which is friendlier. Or, if you insist: if you are using SSH to connect to the server (and the server has an X server running !) then you can look into the `ssh -X` option to view X windows on your remote machine.

Oh and you could look into `scp` command as well (behaves almost just like regular `cp`, but the destination is on another host). That way you could edit on your machine, then copy it via SSH (although you'd want to be careful when copying files directly to the server filesystem)

**Edit:** Also, if you really don't like using the terminal (why though? (-: ), some file managers allow you to get the same functionality of the previous commands purely via GUI ([for example](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-linux-file-manager-to-connect-to-an-sftp-server/)).

Answer (score 0):

You've left out some important information that someone would need to know to answer your questions.  The other posters have made some assumptions.

You've mentioned this "terminal", but it's not clear exactly what that is, or how you're getting to it.  What kind of computer do you have in front of you?  What shell is running in that terminal?  Is the shell running on your local computer, or have you remotely connected to a server and running that shell on the remote computer?

Based on what you said, I have a feeling you're making a remote connection to a server, perhaps using ssh.  You likely have either a Windows or Mac PC in front of you.  In those circumstances, running a GUI editor like Eclipse is possible, but likely not practical.  You would have to have Eclipse installed on that remote computer, and you would be displaying the Eclipse window on your local computer using the X11 protocol.  That takes a lot of bandwidth.

If my assumptions are correct, my recommendations depend on how long you expect you're going to want to stay familiar with this environment.  If you intend to do this sort of work forever, then you should learn vi and Emacs to the best of your ability.  As someone who's been using Emacs likely longer than you've been alive, I'd recommend you learn it, but vi is also a critical skill.

Comment: Yes, I am using a Mac terminal, and I am SSH'ing to a server back on my campus. This is exactly the answer I was looking for, so thanks! Even though I am pretty bummed out with the end result-- guess I do have to actually learn to use emacs after all!

Answer (score -1):

UNIXY systems provide `open` or `gopen`, depending on your OS, that should get the job done. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gopen):

> By default, gopen will open ***filename*** with the application currently assigned to the file's extension. But by specifing the -a flag on the command line you can tell gopen to open the file with another application.

This means that you can use it to open files in your preferred editor
with a line like
 `gopen -a Eclipse file`